# The role of the particle に in ばかものに考えているに思えた。

Tags: particle-に

I came across the following sentence:

> ばかものに考えているに思えた。

Which was translated as:

> Seemed to believe in stupid things.

Now, the first に states IN WHAT someone seemed to believe. We can put this one aside. What is the role of the second one? I would expect for the two verbs to be related through a と particle. So can you help me define the meaning in which に connects two verbs like these?

Comment: 「ばかものに考えているに思えた。」 makes no sense and it is difficult to discuss how a word is used in a sentence that makes no sense.

Comment: 考えているに思えた makes no sense?

Comment: @Gabu This sentence is broken because the two に in this sentence are both used inappropriately. According to the English translation, this sentence must be 「ばかなことを考えているように思えた」.

Comment: Can you give more context (sentences before and after) and verify the above is correct? If it is from a book or other physical media please take a picture and show us.